# Java file not found exception

Tags: java, file, exception

I'm working on a sidescroller and I'm having trouble with my BlockManager Class.  The problem is reading the text file I have in a folder called "Images".  The Images i have in that folder load fine, so I'm not sure whats going on.

Whenever I run my code I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Images\blocksInfo.txt".  The directory of the file I'm trying to read is /Images/blocksInfo.txt.

I'm really confused as to why the directory I'm searching uses forward slashes and eclipse shows them as backslashes when showing the exception.  I think it might have something to do with the string "Images/" I use to search for the file, but I'm not certain

Here's the code, the problem is in the loadBlocksFile method:

```
  public class BlockManager {

  private final static String IMAGE_DIR = "Images/";
  private final static int MAX_BLOCKS_LINES = 15;

  private final static double MOVE_FACTOR = 0.25;  

  private int pWidth, pHeight;    
  private int width, height;     

  private int imWidth, imHeight;  
  private int numCols, numRows;  

  private int xMapHead;    

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList blocksList;   
    // stores Brick objects which makes up the block map

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList[] columnBlocks;
    // Brick objects saved in column order 
    // (faster to search than blocksList)

  private ImageLoader imsLoader;
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private ArrayList blockImages = null;    
         // holds all the images loaded by imsLoader


  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public BlockManager(int w, int h, String fnm, ImageLoader il)
  {
    pWidth = w; pHeight = h;
    imsLoader = il;

    blocksList = new ArrayList();
    loadBlocksFile(fnm);
    initBlocksInfo();
    createColumns();

    moveSize = (int)(imWidth * MOVE_FACTOR);
    if (moveSize == 0) {
      System.out.println("moveSize cannot be 0, setting it to 1");
      moveSize = 1;
    }

    isMovingRight = false;   // no movement at start
    isMovingLeft = false;
    xMapHead = 0;
  }  

  private void loadBlocksFile(String fnm){ 
    String imsFNm = IMAGE_DIR + fnm;
    System.out.println("Reading blocks file: " + imsFNm);

    int numStripImages = -1;
    int numBlocksLines = 0;
    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(imsFNm));
      String line;
      char ch;
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.length() == 0)  
          continue;
        if (line.startsWith("//"))   
          continue;
        ch = Character.toLowerCase( line.charAt(0) );
        if (ch == 's')  
          numStripImages = getStripImages(line);
        else {  
          if (numBlocksLines > MAX_BLOCKS_LINES) 
            System.out.println("Max reached, skipping blocks line: " + line);
          else if (numStripImages == -1) 
            System.out.println("No strip image, skipping blocks line: " + line);
          else {
            storeBlocks(line, numBlocksLines, numStripImages);
            numBlocksLines++;
          }
        }
      }
      br.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I run my code I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Images\blocksInfo.txt".

So the filename you supplied was `"Images\\blocksInfo.txt"`.

> The directory of the file I'm trying to read is /Images/blocksInfo.txt.

So you omitted a leading slash.

Comment: The file name I supply is blocksInfo.txt, "Images/" is appended to the front of that making the file I'm searching for Images/blocksInfo.txt.  Which should be the correct path.  When i print the file name to the console I get Images/blocksInfo.txt, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm quoting your words here, and your error message. They are in contradiction, as is your comment. Make up your mind. Is it `Images` or `/Images`? Resolve that and your problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It wasn't the directory, I was using "BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("imsFNm"));"  Instead of "BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (in));"